# Angular 5 Unit Test: "Can't read property 'get' of undefined in Injector"

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'am writing Unit Test Angular 5 for your Web Application using Karma-Jasmines.
I use Injector to inject Services.

1. Create InjectableObject method:

   ```
   import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
   let appInjectorRef: Injector;
   export const InjectableObject = (injector?: Injector): Injector => {
      if (injector) {
         appInjectorRef = injector;
     }
     return appInjectorRef;
   };
   ```
2. Create BaseComponent class:

   ```
   import { InjectableObject } from './injectableobject.base';
   import { MyDataService} from '../services/mydata.service';

   interface IBaseComponentOptions {
       hotkey?: boolean;
       tableName?: string
   }

   export class BaseComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterContentInit{
       constructor(private opt?: IBaseComponentOptions) {
          const _injector = InjectableObject();

          this._myDataService = _injector.get(MyDataService);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a component extends from BaseComponent:

   ```
   @Component({
       selector: 'app-header',
       templateUrl: './header.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
   })
   export class HeaderComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
       constructor(
           private dataService: MyDataService,
       ){super()}
   }
   ```
4. Create file unit test:
       import { MessageService } from '';
       import { HeaderComponent } from '';

   ```
   describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
      let component: HeaderComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;
      let backend: MockBackend;
      beforeEach(async(() => {
         TestBed.configureTestingModule({
             declarations: [HeaderComponent],
             provides: [MyDataService]
         })
      }).compileComponents();

      beforeEach(() => {
         fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
         component = fixture.componentInstance;
         fixture.detectChanges();
      });

      it('should create', () => {
          expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
   });
   ```

But when I run test, I've got this:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined**

**at "this._myDataService = _injector.get(MyDataService);" in BaseComponent.**

I don't know write unit test to pass this case.
Please everyone help me!
Thanks all!

Comment: Why are you injecting your service this way ? Why don't you simply use a `@Injectable` decorator ?

Comment: Because I want to create a place to inject all service!

Comment: And why would you do that ? You're basically doing the same thing the framework does, you're just adding useless complexity to it ...

Answer (score 0):

Its related to async call.....

Wrap that testcase with fakeAsync call....

```
it('should create', () => {
    fakeAsync(() => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

then import fakeAsync from `@angular/core/testing`

Comment: import fakeAsync from '@angular/core/testing';

Comment: Just wanted to chime on this for others that for some reason finds this post. **This is not a solution**. Wrapping the code in the test this way will make it pass but not for the correct reasons. The code inside of fakeAsync will never run, and therefore nothing is to expect of the test and it passes.